# Typescipt class protected field naming convention

Tags: angular, typescript, naming-conventions, protected

I'm c# developer and start typescript in angular framework now, in normally I try to create a protected field and assign getter/setter to that like this:

```js
export class Test {
    protected _id: number;
    constructor(id: number) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    get id(): number {
        return this._id;
    }
    set id(id: number) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

but in the Angular, there is lint standard for naming fields, and it makes an error on _id.
I try to change the name of the field to Id but this is contrary to programming standards.
what should I do?

Comment: @mbojko you might not have the same linting rules.

Comment: I try to package a library for NPM and it may pass all test and linting standards and be sure it makes a linting error that makes be disable the rules .if you can help me drop some solution but no negative point :(

Comment: I think the lint is correct but it should be ```this._id = id;``` in constructor and setter.

Comment: Turn of tslint rule error by adding this line above  your code // tslint:disable-next-line: variable-name

Answer (score 0):

When you hover over your error/warning, you will see the description of the error and the name of the TSLint rule.

All you have to do is open your root `tslint.json` and change the value of that rule.

I guess it would be [`variable-name`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/variable-name/), but see for yourself.

PS : It isn't a bad practice to change your linter configuration : the bad practice would be for your team & you not to follow it.

Comment: we are working on a macro frontend product and we couldn't change the rules locally.

Comment: @MostafaSaadatnia then change your linting rules wherever they are.